# Looking for Windows Phone 7 design templates

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro

I am just wondering if anyone know good site/images to see various design of windows phone 7 UI (buttons,background,mediaplayer....etc)

for example for web : we have http://www.templatemonster.com/ any many more site 
(i'm not asking for ready made design like web)

i'm wondering if any metro designer developed some good UI and share on internet via website, blog or kind of psd template,Images ...like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link for this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637515%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[See the resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637515%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) provided by microsoft, it is a good place to get started. `Design templates for windows phone 7` has the photoshop layouts. If you ever feel like designing on paper, [this stencil kit](http://www.uistencils.com/products/windows-phone-stencil-kit) might come handy.